# Hidden Field in multiple Forms in Razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Please help me as soon as possible.

I am using jquery tabs and for each tab I have different form so I have multiple forms in the page. I also have a hidden field Id in the page that I have outside of all the forms.Now, when I submit the form, hidden field is coming to be null in the controller. Why it is happening that as I am setting the value to hidden field on select of autocomplete. When User selects the value from autocomplete list , I set value to hidden field.I mean to say hidden field is not empty when I check on the click of submit button click , I checked it with alert and hidden field is showing the value but in controller that hidden field is coming to be empty. This is the first method that I tried. Actually I want to keep hidden field global beacause on save of every form , I need that hidden field beacuse that  Id has to be saved in each table that belongs to each form.The model is same for full page.

```
 FIRST Method:::
    <div id="PageContent"> 
        @Html.HiddenFieldfor(m=>m.fkID)
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Evaluation","SaveTab1"{new AjaxOptions { Onsucess= "DisplayMessage" }))
    {

     <input type="Submit" id="btnTab1" value="Submit" onclick="CheckUser();"/>
    }

      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Evaluation","SaveTab2"{new AjaxOptions { Onsucess= "DisplayMessage" }))
    {
     <input type="Submit" id="btnTab2" value="Submit" />
    }
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-3">

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Evaluation","SaveTab3"{new AjaxOptions { Onsucess= "DisplayMessage" }))
    {
     <input type="Submit" id="btnTab3" value="Submit" />
    }
      </div>
    </div>


    </div> 
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>

    In the second One I placed hidden field in the form that is in the form of first tab.Now, I am getting the model value in the controller.but after the json response I tried to set the value on the success event , the value is coming but on the  submission of second form that hidden field is coming again empty. Please help me to solve this problem.

    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Evaluation","SaveTab1"{new AjaxOptions { Onsucess= "DisplayMessage" }))
    {
@Html.HiddenFieldfor(m=>m.fkID)
     <input type="Submit" id="btnTab1" value="Submit" onclick="CheckUser();"/>
    }

      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Evaluation","SaveTab2"{new AjaxOptions { Onsucess= "DisplayMessage" }))
    {
     <input type="Submit" id="btnTab2" value="Submit" />
    }
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-3">

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Evaluation","SaveTab3"{new AjaxOptions { Onsucess= "DisplayMessage" }))
    {
     <input type="Submit" id="btnTab3" value="Submit" />
    }
      </div>
    </div>


    </div> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function DisplayMessage(Json)
    {
    alert( $("#fkID").val(Json.hdn));
    and Alert is showing the value
     $("#fkID").val(Json.hdn);
    }
    </script>


    In the controller I have done::
    public ActionResult SaveTab1(Model obj)
    {
     tbl ob =new tbl();
    ob.FkId=Obj.fkID;
    after saving, I return
    return json(new{hdn=Obj.fkID})
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hidden field needs to be inside the form.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Evaluation","SaveTab1"{new AjaxOptions { Onsucess= "DisplayMessage" }))
{
 @Html.HiddenFieldfor(m=>m.fkID)
 <input type="Submit" id="btnTab1" value="Submit" onclick="CheckUser();"/>
}
```

Or else it won't be posted when submitted.

You can either add the hidden field to each form or you can use jQuery to append the hidden field to which ever form has been clicked.

**Update**

```
 $('formID').submit(function(){
   $(this).append($('#hiddenID'));  // should append your hidden field to whatever form is being submitted.
 });
```

Comment: Sir, If I keep hidden field in the form, then it is avaialable in the controller only for the first form. No problem, after I get it in the controller , I send it's value again to json response and again sets it's value. If I again sets it's value then It is coming again null for the second form submit and that could be because of it's scope only in First Form. Please clarify that can I use same hidden field in all the forms? and set it's value after json response and can use again in another form submit?

Comment: Yes you should be able to put to the hidden field inside each form.  Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Actually I just want to set a hidden field a value that can retain the same value for each post of Submit from each form.

Comment: Sir, yes Sir, I am using jquery as well as java script.

Comment: No sorry, I am using hidden field of property type string of model.Like in model I have st a property Public string FKId {get;set;} and then converted to in as hidden field in razor view.that's why I am getting the model property in th econtroller beacuse I am using model in the Controller.you can see in above question where I am using the model in controller.

Comment: Check my update to see if that makes sense.  Does your hidden field have an id?  If not you need to generate one in your razor view call.

Comment: @Sandy please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question, otherwise give feedback on what is not resolved. Thanks